# Flutter - How to Change Dropdown Item List Size and Alignment

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using flutter `DropdownButton` for list out something and it worked well while selecting an option from the list the drop-down list appears full screen, I need to give some padding so that the user can cancel the list(hide).

[image: Screen Shot of Problem]

The code:

```
ListView(children: <Widget>[
  ....
  Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.grey,
            style: BorderStyle.solid,
            width: 0.80),
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton(
              isExpanded: true,
              hint: Text('Select Your Height'),
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              iconSize: 20,
              iconEnabledColor: AppColors.PRIMARY_COLOR,
              items: _heights.map((dropDownHieghtItem) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                    value:
                        dropDownHieghtItem['height_id'].toString(),
                    child: Text(dropDownHieghtItem['height_name']));
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String newselectedHieght) {
                setState(() {
                  heightID = newselectedHieght.toString();
                });
              },
              value: heightID)),
    ),......
])
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of using **Text** widget inside **DropdownMenuItem** use **Container** and add custom **TextStyle**
like this:

```
 _heights.map((dropDownHieghtItem) {
      return DropdownMenuItem(
          value:
          dropDownHieghtItem['height_id'].toString(),
          child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(dropDownHieghtItem['height_name'],style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20,color: Colors.red),textAlign: TextAlign.center,)
      )
      );
    }).toList(),
```

Comment: i've tried , it only adds text style but the list appears same as in the screen shot

Comment: You can add any styling you need to the Conatiner 
I added the alignment now you can try it